# how do I search/detect all of the directories/sub-directories within a specified path?

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to list out all of the sub-directories in a given path (see my code)

however, I am very new to python and am wondering what would be the best approach

the below code will produce everything in the folder but I am looking for the directories and sub-directories only

```
import os

def main():

    videosDir = os.listdir("D:\TempServer\Videos\Movies")

    for dir in videosDir:
        dirName = "" + dir
        print(dirName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

any help would be appriecated

Thanks!

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `os.listdir` use `os.walk`. That will distinguish the folders from the files. It loops only on the folders, so you don't even need to filter out the non-folders. If you want the file names, there is a list of the files in each folder (and another list for the subfolders).

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("D:\TempServer\Videos\Movies"):
    print(folderName)
```

Comment: That worked thanks! now I'm try to understand why lol but I think I should look at the documentation? (not sure).....I was playing around with os.walk but was getting all three of the values (the full tulip)...I'm think because there is 3 values defining the 3 values in the for loop separates them

Comment: @littlejiver: Yes, each item from `os.walk` is a tuple with three items. The tuple might have thrown you off the trail. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) is the documentation.